# @autowired field cannot not be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I'm a newbie using Spring framework.

I want to use a class type  "BlaBla", of a different project BlablaProject, in my project "myProject" in Eclipse. Both projects uses Spring framework. To uses BlaBla I add the @autowired annotation in my classe :

```
@Autowired
private Blabla test;
```

I also add in application-context.xml of myProject

```
<context:component-scan base-package="test.domain" use-default-filters="true" />
```

Blabla is in the test.domain package defined in BlablaProject

But I receive the "cannot not be resolved to a type" error. What do I forget to configure, either in BlablaProject or in myProject?

Comment: Have you imported annotation package? `import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;`

Comment: Is the bean type Blabla exposed by the project? Here is a tutorial on using spring autowiring via annotation http://www.journaldev.com/2623/spring-bean-autowire-by-name-type-constructor-autowired-and-qualifier-annotations-example

Comment: this might sound a stupid question, but "cannot be resolved to a type" error.... ehhhh.. can you give the stack of that, i mean to what class it's pointing the issue? because normally if the autowire fails, you should have a null autowired object.. cannot be resolved to a type, if associated to BlablaProject, seems like it cannot resolve the type per se... Is the Blablaproject visibile? I mean, if in your src/main/java of this new project create a simple class with a main that does BlablaProject pj = new BlablaProject(); System.out.println(pj.toString()); does it even compile?

Comment: @witchedwiz There is no stack, it's not while compiling, it's an Eclipse error. As said Paul John I think the Blabla bean is not exposed by BlablaProject